# Sympy, Sum over Piecewise, simplify

Tags: python, sympy

Basically the math expression

```
\sum_{i=0}^n 1_{i==0}
```

expressed in SymPy is this:

```
Sum(Piecewise((1, Eq(i, 0)), (0, True)), (i, 0, n))
```

This can be simplified to

```
1_{n>=0}
```

or if you know that n is always n>=0, this is basically just

```
1
```

How can I get this simplification in SymPy? Simply `simplify` does not work.
Maybe `Piecewise` is also not the best way to express this. Is there a better alternative the same?

---

Another example:

```
Sum(Piecewise((2, Eq(i, 0)), (1, True)), (i, 0, n))
```

Should simplify to:

```
2 + n
```

---

I reported that upstream [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18388).

Comment: Declare `n as: n = symbols('n', integer=True, positive=True)`

Comment: @Navaro: I already have `integer=True, negative=False`. It can also be 0, thus `positive=True` is wrong in my case.

Comment: This is, apparently, not a case that simplification handles. The natural rewrite is just to remove the value for which the value depends on i from the Piecewise and from the sum indices, e.g. `Sum(Piece((a, Eq(i,2)),(b, True)), (i, 0, n))` -> `a + Sum(b, (i, 0, n))  - b`.

Comment: @smichr: But how can I do that? In an automatic way. It should work for both the examples I provided, and many similar examples. Also, can you post that as an answer?